# multiple line graphs in single frame

Tags: r

I have a discharge data that i want to display; observed vs simulated. The data is as follows;

```
Time    observed    simulated
Jan-86  0.105   0.1597
Feb-86  0.0933  0.1259
Mar-86  3.5336  0.41
Apr-86  8.8999  2.494
May-86  5.2431  1.767
Jun-86  0.9747  1.96
Jul-86  0.079   1.98
Aug-86  0.0154  1.729
Sep-86  0.0053  1.419
Oct-86  0.0135  1.121
Nov-86  0.0235  0.8664
Dec-86  0.017   0.658
Jan-87  0.017   0.4925
Feb-87  0.017   0.3855
Mar-87  3.3483  1.089
Apr-87  3.3156  1.704
May-87  0.5563  1.327
Jun-87  0.2565  1.166
Jul-87  0.0446  1.012
Aug-87  0.0096  0.8278
Sep-87  0.0007  0.6567
Oct-87  0.0018  0.5083
Nov-87  0.0139  0.3892
Dec-87  0.0087  0.2953
Jan-88  0.0025  0.2196
Feb-88  0.0017  0.1641
Mar-88  0.0099  0.3858
Apr-88  1.6217  3.929
May-88  0.3398  0.5156
Jun-88  0.762   0.5537
Jul-88  0.0242  0.4985
Aug-88  0.0002  0.4125
Sep-88  0.0003  0.4027
Oct-88  0   0.2918
Nov-88  0   0.2388
Dec-88  0.0005  0.2024
Jan-89  0.0003  0.147
Feb-89  0.0004  0.1157
Mar-89  0.0006  0.3886
Apr-89  6.5433  10.92
May-89  0.8047  1.685
Jun-89  0.7968  1.486
Jul-89  0.0836  1.407
Aug-89  0.0024  1.22
Sep-89  0.0001  0.9965
Oct-89  0   0.7846
Nov-89  0.0005  0.6097
Dec-89  0   0.4636
Jan-90  0   0.3469
Feb-90  0   0.271
Mar-90  0.2724  0.9063
Apr-90  0.3768  2.902
May-90  0.0776  0.5038
Jun-90  0.1327  0.5622
Jul-90  0.0636  0.5068
Aug-90  0.0005  0.4169
Sep-90  0   0.3328
Oct-90  0   0.2611
Nov-90  0   0.2016
Dec-90  0   0.1549
Jan-91  0   0.116
Feb-91  0.0004  0.0904
Mar-91  0.0024  0.0709
Apr-91  0.0056  0.3813
May-91  0.1312  0.6567
Jun-91  0.1033  0.6053
Jul-91  1.1491  0.6226
Aug-91  0.0957  0.5423
Sep-91  0.01    0.4529
Oct-91  0.009   0.374
Nov-91  0.0436  0.3132
Dec-91  0.0629  0.2344
Jan-92  0.0238  0.1775
Feb-92  0.0125  0.1378
Mar-92  2.4242  3.399
Apr-92  2.9119  4.284
May-92  1.0843  1.854
Jun-92  0.1473  1.7
Jul-92  0.3467  1.451
Aug-92  0.0143  1.182
Sep-92  0.0193  2.272
Oct-92  0.035   1.332
Nov-92  0.0132  1.181
Dec-92  0.0353  0.9716
Jan-93  0.0213  0.7097
Feb-93  0.0196  0.5596
Mar-93  0.2553  5.669
Apr-93  3.4093  4.912
May-93  0.4553  1.575
Jun-93  1.4621  1.56
Jul-93  2.7732  2.622
Aug-93  7.4911  1.587
Sep-93  7.7134  1.381
Oct-93  0.4065  1.133
Nov-93  0.3042  0.9257
Dec-93  0.1669  0.7514
Jan-94  0.0756  0.5657
Feb-94  0.0317  0.4464
Mar-94  1.3576  3.802
Apr-94  1.5093  4.446
May-94  0.8696  1.246
Jun-94  0.3097  1.426
Jul-94  4.1223  1.66
Aug-94  0.6915  0.7939
Sep-94  3.9228  0.6434
Oct-94  1.5528  0.5081
Nov-94  3.0506  0.3907
Dec-94  0.6294  0.3053
Jan-95  0.2484  0.2327
Feb-95  0.1053  0.1842
Mar-95  9.4852  7.073
Apr-95  3.8737  3.122
May-95  3.0692  1.754
Jun-95  0.3433  1.386
Jul-95  2.6554  1.297
Aug-95  0.3252  0.9797
Sep-95  0.2854  0.7803
Oct-95  0.2667  0.6097
Nov-95  0.1444  0.4692
Dec-95  0.1098  0.355
Jan-96  0.0696  0.265
Feb-96  0.0399  0.4352
Mar-96  0.0419  0.2793
Apr-96  16.2771 17.33
May-96  25.3653 21.04
Jun-96  0.4064  4.901
Jul-96  0.3028  3.886
Aug-96  0.097   3.1
Sep-96  0.0325  2.51
Oct-96  0.0949  2.009
Nov-96  0.2763  1.614
Dec-96  0.1307  1.252
Jan-97  0.0778  0.9253
Feb-97  0.0661  0.7211
Mar-97  0.0703  0.7519
Apr-97  27.3434 21.65
May-97  4.2895  7.989
Jun-97  0.4939  3.661
Jul-97  6.7193  3.92
Aug-97  0.1174  2.802
Sep-97  0.0858  2.229
Oct-97  2.0501  1.789
Nov-97  0.891   1.644
Dec-97  0.3561  1.288
Jan-98  0.133   0.94
Feb-98  0.8482  2.56
Mar-98  7.2317  6.613
Apr-98  3.7604  4.181
May-98  3.039   2.323
Jun-98  5.3291  2.492
Jul-98  5.6387  2.607
Aug-98  0.1308  1.943
Sep-98  0.0937  1.647
Oct-98  1.4565  1.641
Nov-98  0.7778  1.563
Dec-98  0.5755  1.692
Jan-99  0.0573  1.65
Feb-99  0.0783  1.489
Mar-99  2.3554  7.688
Apr-99  25.3018 18.41
May-99  8.7571  5.154
Jun-99  14.8313 3.564
Jul-99  4.7535  2.423
Aug-99  3.6622  1.898
Sep-99  5.0639  1.524
Oct-99  0.9153  1.186
Nov-99  0.4436  0.905
Dec-99  0.181   0.6864
Jan-00  0.1015  0.5129
Feb-00  1.9763  0.3953
Mar-00  2.5832  0.3083
Apr-00  3.6585  0.2388
May-00  0.9701  0.182
Jun-00  7.1744  0.1605
Jul-00  1.7145  0.1494
Aug-00  0.6677  0.1364
Sep-00  0.1858  0.1195
Oct-00  1.1442  0.0997
Nov-00  15.1503 0.6839
Dec-00  0.5526  0.4275
01-Jan  0.182   0.6061
01-Feb  0.1582  0.5254
01-Mar  0.7527  0.437
01-Apr  18.8305 21
01-May  4.0794  2.765
01-Jun  1.7906  5.399
01-Jul  0.2344  2.615
01-Aug  2.8721  1.896
01-Sep  0.108   1.555
01-Oct  0.0896  1.237
01-Nov  0.6865  0.9588
01-Dec  0.1609  0.7329
02-Jan  0.0987  0.5496
02-Feb  0.081   0.4299
02-Mar  0.0671  0.4125
02-Apr  1.9161  5.189
02-May  2.8088  2.423
02-Jun  18.2132 2.137
02-Jul  2.881   2.783
02-Aug  0.676   1.102
02-Sep  1.309   0.892
02-Oct  0.1844  0.7183
02-Nov  0.1415  0.56
02-Dec  0.0781  0.4277
03-Jan  0.0897  0.3211
03-Feb  0.0191  0.2515
03-Mar  1.1978  2.32
03-Apr  1.4536  2.175
03-May  1.2194  0.9472
03-Jun  2.2049  0.7456
03-Jul  0.1934  0.6395
03-Aug  0.0362  0.5237
03-Sep  0.0047  0.4738
03-Oct  0.0338  0.3477
03-Nov  0.1166  0.2821
03-Dec  0.0301  0.2319
04-Jan  0.0151  0.1851
04-Feb  0.0218  0.1462
04-Mar  2.9284  3.967
04-Apr  5.113   8.21
04-May  14.4488 6.077
04-Jun  8.7876  4.92
04-Jul  0.7572  2.781
04-Aug  0.3186  2.023
04-Sep  1.7134  1.648
04-Oct  0.834   1.385
04-Nov  1.5215  1.571
04-Dec  0.1535  1.175
05-Jan  0.0515  0.8762
05-Feb  0.0535  0.7016
05-Mar  0.5916  2.954
05-Apr  10.2761 12.22
05-May  4.3927  3.95
05-Jun  12.6566 8.826
05-Jul  13.6267 4.855
05-Aug  11.4682 3.241
05-Sep  1.2082  2.454
05-Oct  1.1875  1.986
05-Nov  1.5555  1.566
05-Dec  0.3229  1.294
06-Jan  0.1832  1.055
06-Feb  0.112   0.885
06-Mar  0.3341  3.006
06-Apr  24.8525 19.75
06-May  6.2187  4.442
06-Jun  0.3634  2.697
06-Jul  0.0534  1.889
06-Aug  0.0439  1.571
06-Sep  0.02    1.261
06-Oct  0.0418  0.9836
06-Nov  0.0612  0.7535
06-Dec  0.0747  0.5717
07-Jan  0.0644  0.43
07-Feb  0.0339  0.3319
07-Mar  2.8046  2.675
07-Apr  2.7156  3.412
07-May  0.5788  2.576
07-Jun  8.5705  9.888
07-Jul  1.3929  2.897
07-Aug  0.1146  1.758
07-Sep  0.0374  1.486
07-Oct  0.1637  1.338
07-Nov  0.1599  1.2
07-Dec  0.1165  0.9649
08-Jan  0.054   0.7372
08-Feb  0.024   0.5469
08-Mar  0.04    0.6989
08-Apr  2.3773  9.219
08-May  1.3455  3.223
08-Jun  1.4375  4.011
08-Jul  0.531   2.341
08-Aug  0.0512  1.618
08-Sep  0.0902  1.377
08-Oct  2.8219  1.115
08-Nov  4.7166  0.9028
08-Dec  0.3393  0.8564
09-Jan  0.1303  0.6376
09-Feb  0.1594  0.7089
09-Mar  10.3111 5.402
09-Apr  14.466  14.64
09-May  6.0214  13.73
09-Jun  5.4491  6.086
09-Jul  7.4774  4.059
09-Aug  0.4845  2.885
09-Sep  0.1321  2.208
09-Oct  0.0935  1.755
09-Nov  0.1702  1.367
09-Dec  0.0786  1.183
10-Jan  0.049   1.461
10-Feb  0.0502  0.8349
10-Mar  9.9809  7.328
10-Apr  2.1785  5.341
10-May  5.54    9.544
10-Jun  6.5798  10.35
10-Jul  1.4304  5.972
10-Aug  0.3424  3.768
10-Sep  8.7223  3.844
10-Oct  5.7656  4.88
10-Nov  3.7897  4.978
10-Dec  0.5271  3.289
```

I tried the following codes to display the data

```
require(xts)
data <- read.csv('./flowout13.csv')
dd1<-data.frame(data[2:3])
dd1<-ts(dd1,frequency = 12,start = 1986)
plot(as.xts(dd1),major.format="%y-%m")
title(main="Calibrated observed and simulated discharge",xlab="Time",ylab="discharge in mm")
legend("topleft", inset=0.10, title="Discharge",
       c("observed","simulated","r2=0.8", "NSE=0.60"), fill=terrain.colors(2), horiz=FALSE)
```

And the graph does not show the actual color of the graphs.I want the black lines as observed and red as simulated but it shows different.i do not want the r2 and NSE be in any color they are just the values, i added from different calculations. I also want to change the position of xlab below the dates. Please help out. I am working on r studio.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
plot(as.xts(dd1), major.format="%y-%m", col = terrain.colors(2))
```

[image]

Comment: No i want to plot both values;observed and simulated.and label them. the plots i have produced is okey but the labelling is problem as you can see there is no green line but legend box shows green as observed.